# Nested multidimetional Associative Array foreach

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array with 5 levels, can I start a foreach on the 3rd level?

```
foreach($people['group']['person'] as $key => $value)
```

...........

or will it only give me the first?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing this?  The whole of 20 seconds of testing would give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the item you want to iterate over is an array or an iterable object, it will work.

```
$test1 = array();
$test1['level1'] = array( 'level2' => 
    array( 'level3' => 
        array( 'level4' => 
            array( 'one', 'two', 'three' ))));


foreach($test1['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4'] as $k => $v) 
    echo( $k . ': ' . $v . '<br>');
```

Will output:

```
0: one 
1: two 
2: three
```